# conditions for two automorphisms of a covering space be homotopic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If $X\rightarrow Y$ is a covering space, and $\sigma\ne\tau\in Aut(X/Y)$. Under what assumptions on $X,Y,\sigma,\tau$ would $\sigma,\tau$ be homotopic?

Edit: I'm specifically interested in the case where $X$ has nontrivial fundamental group. Even more specifically, I'm interested in the case where $X,Y$ are fibrations of elliptic curves over $S,T$ respectively, and $X\rightarrow Y$ is the pullback of a covering $S\rightarrow T$.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is contractible, then $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are certainly homotopic. If $X$ is the universal cover, this happens if and only if $\pi_i(Y) = 0$ for $i \geq 2$; that is, $Y$ is a $K(G, 1)$ ([Eilenberg-MacLane space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space)). For every group $G$, there exists a space $K(G, 1)$, so there are many such example.

If $G = \mathbb{Z}$, $K(G, 1) = S^1$ which has contractible universal cover $\mathbb{R}$. More generally, if $G = \mathbb{Z}^n$ then $K(G, 1) = (S^1)^n$ which has contractible universal cover $\mathbb{R}^n$. Other examples of spaces with contractible universal cover are compact oriented surfaces which are connected sums of tori.

Comment: can you say any stronger statement which only depends on the relation between $\sigma$ and $\tau$ and $\pi_1(X)$... I dont know much anout this kind of result..but still this result looks very weak to me...can it be possible to generalize this problem??? thankyou in advance.

Comment: @AnubhaV At the very least, you cannot say anything by making assumptions about $\pi_1(X)$ alone. The nontrivial deck transformation (the antipodal map) with respect to $S^n \to \Bbb{RP}^n$ is homotopic to the other deck transformation (the identity) if and only if $n$ is odd.